# Docker volume bind breaks python script CLI entry_point

Tags: python, docker

Alright so I have a fairly basic python `click` CLI application that when ran with a bound volume in a container (live dev on files) appears to break the `entry_point` I have in `setup.py`

Running either of the following commands

```
$ docker run -it -v $(pwd):/opt/app gdax
$ docker run -it --mount src=$(pwd),target=/opt/app,type=bind gdax
```

I get the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdax", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3144, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3128, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3157, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 984, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 870, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'gdax-cli' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir /opt/app
COPY . /opt/app


WORKDIR /opt/app

RUN pip install --editable .

CMD ["gdax", "--help"]
```

## setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name='gdax-cli',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['app'],
    install_requires=[
        'click==6.7',
        'gdax==1.0.6'
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        gdax=app:cli
    ''',
)
```

## /usr/local/bin/gdax <- on container

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'gdax-cli','console_scripts','gdax'
__requires__ = 'gdax-cli'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('gdax-cli', 'console_scripts', 'gdax')()
    )
```

If I don't bind the volume I can execute the script just fine but I lose the ability to edit the files on the host machine. I'm fairly confident this has something to do with how binding "overwrites" the files and will break `/usr/local/bin/gdax` ability to load the files which is placed there by `setuptools`. Is there anyway to circumvent this (outside of calling `python app.py` in the container)?

Comment: You are overwriting the `gdax_cli.egg-info` folder. The answer to this probably depends on your use case. Are you trying to use the same image as the development and eventual deployment image? Or are you only looking for a local development environment to keep Python off of the host? Maybe you could amend your question to elaborate on your goals so I could better create an answer.

Comment: Ahh I see. I was using it in my case as a development environment by binding the volume but it could very easily be a deployed image. If you post the answer I will mark it correct. I mention that I am using it as a development environment in the parenthesis in the opening sentence.

Comment: @Adam I'm running into the same issue for the exact same use case. Did you come up with any workaround for this (copying the `.egg-info` folder out of the container into the host...!?), or did you resort to calling the CLI via module directly during development?

Answer (score 2):

When installing pip as editable in the current directory, the `<package>.egg-info` directory needs to be present for python to find the installed package.

One can “whitelist” directories from being overwritten by a `docker-compose.yml` mount point, like so:

```
services:
  myapp:
    image: mafrosis/myapp:dev
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/.git
      - /app/myapp.egg-info
```

In this example, both the `.git` and `myapp.egg-info` directories will be present when the container starts.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody interested in calling the Python `entry_points` console scripts via `docker-compose run` during development. Copying the `.egg-info` folder into the mounted host directory from the running container one time works for me.

*Copy the `.egg-info` directory to host from running container. Turn mounting off beforehand so the `.egg-info` directory is not overriden.*

```
sudo docker cp <container id>:/path/to/package/in/container/package.egg-info /path/to/mounted/package/on/host/package.egg-info
```

*Re-enable mounting, the needed `.egg-info` folder is now present so the installed entry_points should work and you can run commands like:*

```
sudo docker-compose run <service name> <entry_point console script name> [OPT] [ARG]
```

For this to work, the Python package needed to be installed in development mode in the image, like with `RUN pip install -e /path/to/package/`, because otherwise the `.egg-info` file will not be in the symlinked source code directory, I guess.

*Of course, the alternative, like @Adam mentions, is to always call the `CLI` scripts directly like:*

```
sudo docker-compose run <service name> python /path/to/package/cli.py [OPT] [ARG]
```